# Core data Relation Fault (not lazy loading). Relations disappear

Tags: iphone, core-data, entity-relationship, one-to-many, fault

I have a core data database which has (for now) 2 entities Product and CompetingProduct, CompetingProduct relation is set to-many with products.

I create 2 mock Products and 2 mock Competing products and set relation between them .. everything works files.. Saved to database, also NSlog, "po" them.. all is good.

Now.. when i **restart the app** or i request all objects of *competing product* type from a **different view**..  i get **Relation fault** for the relation between Competing Product and Products (although i added them earlier, and saved)

I know that about the lazy loading of data core but here is not the case because when i try [NSSet allObjects] (also po, nslog - nothing) it returns 0 objects which normally should get objects.

Note: Immediately after i call saveChanges - all things work

Absolutely **ANY** help will be greatly **appreciated** and **win** you **my respect** and of course a **couple of beers**

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the description of the problem correctly, it could be caused by not having a recipocal relationship set from CompetingProduct to Product.

If the relationship is:

```
Product-->CompetingProduct
```

...and not:

```
Product<-->CompetingProduct
```

... then you will be able to find CompetingProducts starting with a Product but you will be able to find a Product by starting with a CompetingProduct.

If this is not the problem then it sounds like you may have multiple context and are not saving the one the changes are made in.

Comment: yup. it seems the inverse relation was the problem. Thanks!!

Comment: how do i set your answer as the answer?

Comment: I believe you click on the tick besides this answer - it'll turn green and that answer is now marked as the approved answer.